# Jackson's @JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CUSTOM, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type") reads all fields of JSON except for "type"

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I stepped through each line of code, but I think it's how Jackson handles polymorphism internally.

Using the classic example of `Dog` and `Cat` extending `Animal`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CUSTOM, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(AnimalTypeIdResolver.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class Animal implements Serializable {
    public AnnotatorBundleConfig(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
```

The dog class :

```
public class DogAnimal extends Animal {
    @JsonCreator
    public DogAnimal(
        @JsonProperty(value="name", required=true) String name,
        @JsonProperty(value="bark_decibel") int bark_decibel)
    {
    super(name);
    this.bark_decibel = bark_decibel;}
```

The cat class:

```
public class CatAnimal extends Animal {
    @JsonCreator
    public CatAnimal(
        @JsonProperty(value="name", required=true) String name,
        @JsonProperty(value="meow_level") int meow_level)
    {
    super(name);
    this.meow_level = meow_level;}
```

The `AnimalTypeIdResolver` is a typical TypeIdResolver that extends `AbstractTypeIdResolver`.

For some very odd reason, `bark_decibel` and `meow_level` are deserialized from JSON, but `type` is getting in as `null`. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: [Jackson - @JsonTypeInfo property is being mapped as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611199/jackson-jsontypeinfo-property-is-being-mapped-as-null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `visible=true` for `@JsonTypeInfo`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.CUSTOM, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible=true)
```

Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146357/3831137)